# How to extract certain numbers from a text file that also contains letters in C++?

Tags: c++, fstream, getline

I am trying to figure out how to extract values from a text file as a type double so that they can be used in calculations.

I have a text file that is formatted like:

```
parameter1        parameter2         parameter3
50                0                  0.1
```

And I want to extract only the numbers. 
This is one of my attempts (I have been working for hours trying to figure out how to do this).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int MAX = 80;
    char buffer[MAX];
    string input;
    double j;

    ifstream param0;
    param0.open("param0.txt");
    char ch;
    while (param0)
    {
        param0.get(ch);
        cout << ch;
    }

    getline(param0, input);
    param0 >> j;
    while (param0)
    {
        cout << j << endl;
        getline(param0, input);
        param0 >> j;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: your first loop reads to the end of the file and simply displays the data. Why would you do that. Take that loop out, or close and reopen the file.

Comment: You could rewind the file after displaying it but it might be better to just print it as it is assigned.

Comment: Why are you using `param0 >> j`  and getline at the same time.  You only need one or the other depending on whether you want to read the whole line or just read one value.

Answer (score 0):

this code

```
   char ch;
    while (param0)
    {
        param0.get(ch);
        cout << ch;
    }
```

runs to the end of the file. All reads after it will return nothing. Either take this loop out or rewind the file `param0.rewind()`

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea of the code should be:

```
std::string line;
double p1, p2, p3;
std::string more;

while (std::getline(in, line)) {
    std::istringstream iss{line};
    if (iss >> p1 >> p2 >> p3 && !(iss >> more)) {
        std::printf("p1=%f, p2=%f, p3=%f\n", p1, p2, p3);
    } else {
        std::printf("invalid line: %s\n", line.c_str());
    }
}
```

In plain words, the code says: a line is valid if it contains three numbers and nothing more.

C++ purists will say that I shouldn't use printf in C++, but I like the separation between formatting and the actual data.

Answer (score 0):

suggestion :

- best to check if you open the file correctly.
- close the file once you finish with it.

you can just use the >> operator if you reading everything in one line. It doesn't matter if its string or double as long as if you pass the correct storage variable;

```
string param1;
string param2;
string param3;
double j,k,l;

ifstream file("test.txt",std::ios::in);
if (!file.is_open())
    std::cout << "failed to open " << endl;

while (file)
{
    file >> param1 >> param2 >>param3; // getting as strings
    cout << param1 <<", "<< param2<<", "<< param3<<endl; 
    file >> j >> k >> l;               //getting as doubles
    cout << j <<", " << k <<", "  << l<<endl;
}

file.close();
return 0;
```

output

> parameter1, parameter2, parameter3
>   50, 0, 0.1

Comment: the assumption in this code is that there is one header row and one data row

Comment: @pm100 . that's correct. the question seems to be though how to read doubles from the text file.